# Revert merged branch

Tags: version-control, merge, mercurial

I accidentally merged а branch to default then pushed to the remote repository. So my question is how to revert the merge on local and on the remote repository?
There are no merge/branch/commits made after that

Already tried with

```
hg update -C
hg update -C -r .
hg rollback (there is no rollback transaction available)
```

but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options

1) hg revert to remove the chages from default (this should be safe but leaves the fact the merge happened in history)

2) hg strip on the remote repo and make everyone clone again (this is unsafe and probably not viable unless you have a very small team under direct control)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend closing the default branch with the bad commit, and committing new changesets to default from before the merge happened.  This keeps history queries correct.  Example:

[image]

`test` branch was mistakenly merged to default.  Close the branch and commit from pre-merge (Rev 1).  A simple "hg revert -r 1 --all" on default would backout the merge, but the test branch changesets would still appear to be ancestors of the default tip.  Closing the bad merge head keeps history looking accurate.